# Image won't load

Tags: java, image

i am trying to load an image using this methods.
I am asking for my image here:

```
private BufferedImage image = controller.loadImage("/paddle.png");
```

And the loadImage method is

```
public BufferedImage loadImage(String path) {
    BufferedImage image = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path));
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
}
```

I added "res" to my class folder also but nothing seems to work.
My project explorer looks like this : http://prntscr.com/hmar35
EDIT: I also tried URL loading but failed to work either,the code for URL loading is:

```
 public BufferedImage loadImage(String path) {
     BufferedImage image = null;
     try {
         URL link = Controller.class.getResource(path);
         image = (BufferedImage) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(link);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
}
```

Comment: "nothing seems to work" is not a useful problem description. Please be more specific.

Comment: Just updated the question with the URL loading code,i hope it helps

Comment: Nope, not at all.

Comment: Well what else can i provide you with?Some things i checked was the image name "paddle.png",i tried removing the "/" still didnt work.I checked the code multiple times for errors but i cant seem to find any.I have no idea what to do next..

Comment: You can start by answering my implied question. **What** doesn't work?

Comment: Yes I did.The exception thrown is NullPointer,i should have added that in my question,my bad.I'm guessing it doesn't properly load the image from my res folder but i cant seem to find the issue

Comment: The code in the first `loadImage` should work, but you have to define the folder `res` as a source-folder. The problem here is that the path is wrong and can't find the image.

Comment: @Edwardth Yeah that's why I got frustrated,i added res as a class folder.My other images load properly(level0,level1) but paddle.png just won't load.I also refreshed my project

Comment: Look into the bin folder, what files are there? Also try to clean your project and rebuild it, does this change something?

Comment: Also the folder `res` looks on the image like a library-folder and not like an source-folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path));
```

where path = "paddle.png" in your case.

If your res folder is set as a source folder, and "paddle.png" is located directly inside of the res folder, you do not need to add a "/" to the file path.

Note:  Also make sure you refresh your project to make sure all files are recognized.

Comment: Doesn't work either,I also tried cleaning and rebuilding my project as @Edwardth suggested and it still doesn't work.I even created a level2.png and that even loaded.

Comment: Can u post the error message you are getting when loading the image?

Comment: After a combining your answers and a lot of luck I guess it worked,the image loaded properly.Id like to thank you guys for your time.Do I manually close my Question or something?I am new here and trying to blend in

Comment: If you accept someone's response as an answer, then you closed the question.